# Join two tables in Laravel with conditions

Tags: laravel, join, relational-database

I have two tables that I wanted to join with the following condition that only show products with product type 1 and product should be available in img tbl and also should not have noImg.jpg

```
products tbl                  img tbl
+-------------------------+   +--------------------------------+
| id   | product_type         | id    | product_id | file
---------------------------   +---------------------------------
| 123  |  1                    | 1    |123         | 1.jpg
| 234  |  2                    | 2    |234         | noImg.jpg
| 345  |  1                    | 3    |345         | 3.jpg
```

I did the following in Laravel but it seems that query is not correct because its not giving me the correct results.

```
Product::join('img', function($join) {
                                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'img.product_id')
                                ;
                             })
                                ->where('img.file', '!=', 'noImg.jpg')
                                ->where('products.product_type', 1)
                                ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: Could you provide the result that you get from the query and the result that you want to get from the query?

Comment: What I am getting: All products are appearing with images,  with  noImg.jpg and also the are appearing where they don't have any image. So it seems that query is not working as it should.
What I want is to get the products list where Images are available in img table and also if product have noImg.jpg then don't show that product as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Product::rightJoin('img', function($join) {
            $join->on('products.id', '=', 'img.product_id')
            ;
        })
            ->where('img.file', '<>', 'noImg.jpg')
            ->where('products.product_type','=',1)
            ->get();
```

Comment: I am still getting the products with noImg.jpg in the listing :( . Also I am getting the products which are not available in the img table which should not appear in case they are not available in the img table

Comment: what is the name of your image table ?? img?? right??

Comment: I tried with right Join as well, but didn't worked.. Results are similar as before

Comment: When I dd() the values I find something Interesting. All the products that are not available in the image table are not listing but some of the products that were delete but they still have product_id in the img table are appearing. Can we also add a condition here if product_id in the img table found but not in the products table, they should not appear as well?

Comment: i don't find any reason why your code give you wrong answer.beacuse all the process is correct.you can give condition & check this

Comment: Also products that are available in the products tbl but they are in the img table are also appearing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Product::rightJoin('img', function($join) {
    $join->on('products.id', '=', 'img.product_id')
        ->where('img.file', '!=', 'noImg.jpg');
    })
    ->where('products.product_type', '=', 1)
    ->paginate(100);
```

I believe img and products are your table names.